# Can't change "int" in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, int, sprite-kit

I have had a very weird experience with Objective C and xCode these last couple of days. I'm now turning to you guys for some quick help.

I'm simply trying to set up and int, call in damage(the amount of damage this object is supposed to do) and increase it if a void function is called.

```
    -(void) increaseDagage{
damage = damage + 100;
NSLog(@"%f", damage);
}
```

I have tried setting the int damage up as a int and also as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float damage;
```

The problem is that when I print "damage" it hasn't increased... 
I also have a function that returns the amount of damage this object does and it returns the wrong value.
I can't figure out why this isn't doing what I want... 
I also have an int called health, which is basically the same thing and works fine.

Here's the full class if you want to see that too,

```
    //
//  Character.m
//  TD
//
//  Created by Victor Appelgren on 2014-12-23.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Victor Appelgren. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Character.h"
#import "constants.h"
#import "Level.h"
#import "GameViewController.h"


@interface Character (){

    SKSpriteNode *character;
    float health;
    float maxHealth;
    Level *level;
    GameViewController *gVC;
    BOOL dead;
    int damage;
}

//@property (nonatomic, assign) float damage;

@end

@implementation Character

-(id) init {

    if (self = [super init]){

        damage = 100;

        dead = NO;

        // Load health 
        maxHealth = 200;
        health = 200.0;

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:character.frame.size.width / 2];
        [self addChild:character];
    }

    return  self;
}

-(void) doDamageType:(int)type{ // here a type is passed in to tell how much damage is being done. 
    if (type == 1){
        health = health - 20;


    } else if (type == 2){
        health = health - 40;

    }

    if (health <= 0){

        [self removeFromParent];
        dead = YES;
    }
}
-(void) increaseDagage{
    damage = damage + 100.0;
   // NSLog(@"%f", _damage);
}
-(int) returnDamage{
    return damage;
}

-(BOOL) returnDead{
    return dead;
}
-(float) returnHealth{
    return health;
}
-(float) returnMaxHealth{
    return maxHealth;
}
@end
```

Here's the output I'm getting,

2015-02-22 01:28:27.722 TD[279:43180] 200.000000

2015-02-22 01:28:30.327 TD[279:43180] 200

2015-02-22 01:28:30.496 TD[279:43180] 200

2015-02-22 01:28:30.644 TD[279:43180] 200

2015-02-22 01:28:30.809 TD[279:43180] 200

first is initial value and the rest is from when the function is being called

What is wrong....
I might be missing something here but can't seem to find the problem

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using the property or the class instance?

Comment: Are you sure you are using same `Character` instance every time you call  `increaseDagage`?

Comment: You don't show us the code that's calling this.  I'm guessing you create a new Character instance every time you call `increaseDamage`.

Comment: You kinda need to show us the real code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've created two different `damage` variables -- one in your `.h` and another in your `.m`. The one in your .h is public and accessible from your `.m` using `self.damage`. The one you've declared in your `.m` is private and accessible simply using `damage`. So the problem here is that you're accessing the *public* version of your `damage` from the other class, but you're actually manipulating the *private* version within your class.

So I'd recommend changing the following methods and property declarations of your .m as follows:

```
// ***Remove the private declaration of damage***
@interface Character (){

    SKSpriteNode *character;
    float health;
    float maxHealth;
    Level *level;
    GameViewController *gVC;
    BOOL dead;
}

@end

@implementation Character

// ***And add "self." before each instance of damage***
-(id) init {

    if (self = [super init]){

        self.damage = 100;

        dead = NO;

        // Load health 
        maxHealth = 200;
        health = 200.0;

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:character.frame.size.width / 2];
        [self addChild:character];
    }

    return  self;
}

-(void) increaseDagage{
    self.damage = self.damage + 100.0;
   // NSLog(@"%f", self.damage);
}
-(int) returnDamage{
    return self.damage;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error in your method name : increaseDagage
I am guessing this should be increaseDamage

You also seem to be creating your own setters and getters. I would read up on the usage of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Several things jump out:

1. Your method is called increaseDa**g**age. Do you get any error message in Xcode's console when you call it?
2. You are not telling us whether you are getting any error or warning messages from the code. You should be getting some.
3. You keep talking about `int`s, but the log statement and property you define are `float`s.
4. You are not `@synthesize`ing your float `damage` property. So that means that it will create its own `_damage` instance variable to store the value and not use your `damage` instance variable (which would be the wrong type anyway).
5. You are logging `_damage`, not `damage`.

In short, the code, as written, mixes up two completely different things.